# Is there a better way to handle this in php while?

Tags: php

I know this is simple for you guys but I am not able to apply my brain.

**I want to print** `<p>` **with same content n times depending on the value of n**.

```
<?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
if($row['i'] == 1) {
<p>Content</p>
} else if($row['i'] == 2) {
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
} else if($row['i'] == 3) {
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
}
```

If `$row['i'] == 100` then i have to write 100 times.

Any Better Solution. Thanks.

Comment: save the content in you row, then get them with row['i']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [for](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php).

> [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping_for.asp): PHP for loops execute a block of code a specified number of times.

In your case, specified number of times will be `$row['i']`.

```
for($i=0;$i<$row['i'];$i++){
    echo '<p>Content</p>';
}
```

Comment: @Phoenix is this the result you wanted. output same content 100 times???

Comment: @KrisRoofe yes i want same content so i can print stars according rating number. Thats y i need this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Use a `for loop` inside `while` and add upper limit to `$row['i']`; so it will print your content as many times as the value of `$row['i']`

```
<?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    for($i=0;$i<$row['i'];$i++){
    echo '<p>Content</p>';
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this code will help you:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $j=1;
    for($i=0;$i<$j;$i++){
        echo '<p>Content</p>';
    }
    $j++;
}
```